# Can I use an opto-isolator or opto-coupler instead of a relay to operate AC source?

Tags: microcontroller, relay, power-electronics, opto-isolator

I am designing light control board using a micro controller. As I want to make my circuit board smaller, I am thinking of using an opto-isolator or opto-coupler instead of using relays.

Is it OK to replace a relay with  an opto-isolator" or opto-coupler? Can an opto-isolator work on more current?

Comment: I think you meant solid state relay or TRIAC.

Comment: Relay can be both SSR and general Relay and replacement with Optoisolator and Triac...@RyanGriggs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your load is AC AND low power then some opto-isolators will work such as the MOC3021. It has a triac output capable of driving a low power load in the order of a few mA but, more likely you would want to drive a more powerful device such as this: -

[image]

The external triac would typically be a BT136 and there are a pile of google images [**here**](https://www.google.com/search?q=triac%20moc3021&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixyOeWnZTRAhWLA8AKHX-XAikQ_AUICCgB&biw=1224&bih=893#tbm=isch&q=BT136%20moc3021) that show this type of configuration. The BT136 comes in a T0-220 package that isn't that small but maybe some space saving can be achieved. A lower power BT131-600 could handle 100 watt loads but RMS current is limited to below 1 amp. It is available in a T0-92 package.

You could also consider using a solid-state-relay although a lot of them will contain pretty much the above Triac circuit or back-to-back MOSFETs: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [bristolwatch.com](http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele2/acdcssr/4a.png))</sub>